KMM: composeApp:embedAndSignAppleFrameworkForXcode doesn't get updated
I've struggled for a quite some time embedding the composeApp module into the iOS build when building from XCode. I've managed to get it working on a simulator for no apparent reason - either restart of something or I started a gradle which linked the two.
My problem is, XCode still fails whenever I try to build the app on my Mac, giving me No such module ComposeApp. And while it works on simulator devices, the code updates don't seem to take effect, as the app is crashing on No definition found for type 'ui.login.UserOperationService'. Check your Modules configuration and add missing type and/or qualifier! but I've renamed that class to UserOperationServiceTEST like an hour ago just to test if it updates - and it doesn't.
So I suppose there is a problem with the ComposeApp module being embedded within iosApp module either way.
This is my Compile Kotlin framework script: if [ "YES" = "$OVERRIDE_KOTLIN_BUILD_IDE_SUPPORTED" ]; then echo "Skipping Gradle build task invocation due to OVERRIDE_KOTLIN_BUILD_IDE_SUPPORTED environment variable set to \"YES\"" exit 0 fi cd "$SRCROOT/.." ./gradlew :composeApp:embedAndSignAppleFrameworkForXcode 

Based on the documentation, this should be sufficient, yet, it clearly isn't.
Am I missing something? Is there a gradle script I can run in Android Studio, which would link the two manually?

EDIT: the script should be run without exception


open report navigator tab, go to build and check out script output to see if there're any errors

@PhilDukhov I've updated my question. The script seems no sign of issues in reports. In debug, I can't really decipher anything, can't find any script output either.

I've tried clearing build files and cache of Android Studio and it seems to cripple the simulator device build now too, with build failing on "No such module ComposeApp", the same way my mac as a run device has until now. It's clearly worked once from some run, only cached the ComposeApp in the case of running it on a simulator and never updated it again.

After three painful days, I figured out what was wrong with my configuration. For anyone struggling the same way, it was very useful for me to create a blank project via the Kotlin Multiplatform Wizard, try to run it, then, compare the differences between my project and the blank project that run correctly.
The very answer to my problem was within build.gradle - thus, not anything within the iosApp folder itself. I incorrectly set the baseName property within iosTarget.binaries.framework { to my package name during the development. However, after setting it baseName = ComposeApp the project actually started working on every device. Both simulators, and macOS.

I built a completely new project from wizard. But again it says No such module 'ComposeApp' when i import ComposeApp


Create your iosMain folder at the level of androidMain / desktopMain

Add into your build.gradle.kts and SYNC
kotlin {
 listOf(
     iosX64(),
     iosArm64(),
     iosSimulatorArm64()
 ).forEach { iosTarget ->
     iosTarget.binaries.framework {
         baseName = "ComposeApp"
         isStatic = true
    }
 }

}

Follow instructions on this guide

In step 3 make sure you put the right name of your framework, in my case it was composeApp.



cd "$SRCROOT/.."
./gradlew :composeApp:embedAndSignAppleFrameworkForXcode


Double click on icon on the top of your left menu in XCode, Select your Target (not your Project), Build Settings, in the search bar type "Framework Search Paths"
Double click the field on the right of Debug, click (+) sign and add:


$(inherited)
$(SRCROOT)/../shared/build/xcode-frameworks/$(CONFIGURATION)/$(SDK_NAME)
$(SRCROOT)/../composeApp/build/xcode-frameworks/$(CONFIGURATION)/$(SDK_NAME)

Do the same for Release

Xcode menu -> Product -> Clean Build Folder...
Run your app


The problem is related in the build.gradle file, You should have something like listOf( iosX64(), iosArm64(), iosSimulatorArm64() ).forEach { iosTarget -> iosTarget.binaries.framework { baseName = "ComposeApp" isStatic = true } }, this should solve the problem

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
